# Is the phrase 'sell premium' another way of saying 'sell an option'

Tags: options

In options lingo, when people say 'sell premium' or 'short premium', they pretty much mean selling an option, correct? i.e Sell premium is just another way of saying 'sell an option'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, selling premium is just selling options. It's usually used to talk about out-of-the-money options without coverage from underlying securities which you expect to expire worthless.

More "sophisticated" ways to sell premium would include selling options strangles or straddles which allow you to sell more premium if you have more specific beliefs about the price action.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, selling premium is selling an option that contains premium over it's intrinsic value. Out-of-the-money options contain no intrinsic value, at the money and near the money options contain premium over the intrinsic value. The deeper in-the-money go, the less premium there is.